# Open same script with different arguments in multiple cmd windows

Tags: python, cmd

I need to print X in different cmd windows without waiting result for each window using loop or without

Code below is not working

```
url = [
    'world',
    'technology',
    'entertainment',
    'economics',
    'science',
    'medicine',
    'games',
    'sports',
    'cars',
    'movies',
    'art',
    'music',
    'travel',
    'forex',
    ]

def my_function(x):
    print(x)

for x in url:
    os.system("start /wait cmd /c {my_function(x)}")
```

Comment: If you don't want to wait, why are you using the `/wait` option?

Comment: The usage of [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) being deprecated since many years and should not be used anymore in newly written Python scripts results on Windows in using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to run in background `%ComSpec% /c` with the string defined in the Python script appended as additional arguments. So there is executed in your case `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /wait cmd /c ...`.

Comment: The internal command `start` of `cmd.exe` calls also the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` with a [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure instructing `CreateProcess` to open a new console window to run `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the argument(s) passed to command `start` passed by first `cmd.exe` to the command `start`. All that multiple executions of `cmd.exe` using `CreateProcess` with a `STARTUPINFO` structure with various values for the structure elements do not make sense ever.

Comment: The better solution is using first [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) in Python script to get the string value of environment variable `SystemRoot` and use the string `C:\Windows` if there is very unlikely returned `null` and concatenate this string with the Windows directory with the string `"\\System32\\cmd.exe"` to get the fully qualified file name of the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe`. Then use the `subprocess.Popen` of the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run the Windows Command Processor with the arguments ...

Comment: ... `/D` (`cmd` option) and `/K` (one more `cmd` option) and the `cmd` internal command `echo` and the next string from the array `url` with `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` as `python.exe` should not wait for self-termination of `cmd.exe` which does not happen because of option `/K` until the user enters `exit` or presses __Ctrl+C__ or __Ctrl+Break__ or clicks on __X__ symbol of the console window and with `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. There can be even used `subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and `subprocess.STARTUPINFO` with appropriate values to control where each console window is opened.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd:

- /c   Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.
- /k   Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

For me the following works to open a new cmd window and execute "someCommand":

```
os.system("start cmd /k someCommand")
```

In your case, "start cmd /k {my_function(x)}"  will start a new cmd and execute "{my_function(x)}" which is probably not what you want to do.

If you want to "print" it, you either need to use "echo" or start a new python program.

Look at the following examples:

```
for x in url:
    # echos x
    os.system(f"start cmd /k echo {x}")


for x in url:
    # Starts the python script someScript.py and gives it x as a parameter
    os.system(f"start cmd /k python someScript.py {x}")
```